# JUnit test for synchronized method

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, junit, synchronized

I have created a Spring Boot app. And I have one Synchronized method there. I want to create JUnit test to test if this method is Synchronized or not. Here's the class and the method:

```
public class FileManager {


public synchronized void saveTheFile(String theTemperature, String cityName) throws IOException {
    InputStream streamIn = toInputStream(theTemperature, "UTF-8");
    OutputStream streamOut = new FileOutputStream(cityName + ".txt", true);
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(streamIn, streamOut);
    } finally {

        IOUtils.closeQuietly(streamIn);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(streamOut);
    }

  }

}
```

I guess I need to use multithreading for this, but I've got no idea even how to start my @Test. Please, advise!

Comment: Looks like you don't need to synchronize anything here, as the only used variables are immutable parameters. Unless `toInputStream` deals with shared resources?

Comment: Have you tried ConcurrentUnit https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit ?

Comment: I can show you all my code if you want, but to put it shortly my app gets request (city name) from the user and saves the temperature in this city to a file with a city name. After that app gets the temperature in this city every hour and saves it to the same file until the app is not killed :) The idea of synchronization has come out of the thought that few users can request the same city at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact you do not use any mutable state I don't think you need to synchronize anything at all.

However, as far as testing concurrency is concerned, I suggest you to use `tempus-fugit` library ( http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/)

Using this library, it is super easy to write any tests concerning multithreading and concurrency:

```
@RunWith(ConcurrentTestRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {
  @Test
  public void test1() {}

  @Test
  public void test2() {}
}
```

According to docs:

> Each test method within a class will run on its own thread and in
>   parallel with any other test methods in that class. So, the number of
>   threads for a given test class will be equal to the number of test
>   methods within that class.